# Spectral norm bound on adjacency matrix from an Erdos-Renyi graph

Tags: random-graphs

Let $G(n,p)$ be an Erdos-Renyi graph, where $p \sim \log^k(n) /n$ for small fixed integer $k$. If $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then I am looking for a sharp upper bound on $\|A-\mathbb{E}[A]\|$ that holds with high probability, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm.

There are nice results from the random matrix theory community (e.g., Furedi+Komlos [1] and Vu [2]), which tell us the eigenvalues of $A-\mathbb{E}[A]$ follow the semicircle law. In particular, see Theorem 1.4 of [2]. However, how sharp are those bounds when $p \sim \log^k(n) /n$? What are the best known upper bounds for $\|A-\mathbb{E}[A]\|$ when $p \sim \log^k(n) /n$?

I am also interested in upper bounds when A is replaced by the Laplacian (i.e., diagonal matrix with the degrees of the vertices minus A).

Thank you very much in advance!

REFERENCES:

[1] Furedi+Komlos, The eigenvalues of random symmetric matrices, 1981. [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_komlos_cca1981_random_eig.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ez-furedi/PUBS/furedi_komlos_cca1981_random_eig.pdf)

[2] Vu, Spectral norms of random matrices, 2007. (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00493-007-2190-z.pdf)

Comment: To my knowledge, the sharpest bounds have been obtained in F. Benaych-Georges, C. Bordenave, and A. Knowles, “Spectral radii of sparse random matrices”, Ann. Inst. Henri Poincaré Probab. Stat. 56:3 (2020), 2141–2161. http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/19-AIHP1033

Comment: If $k>1$, the degrees are very well concentrated around $pm$, so the spectral information on $A$ directty translates to spectral information on the Laplacian.

Comment: If you are interested in the $k=1$ regime, the relationship between the spectrum of the Laplacian and $A$ are less direct, because the degrees are not concentrated, see Exercise 3.4 in Bollobas' book Random Graphs.

Comment: Thank you, @MikaeldelaSalle! That's very helpful. Corollary 3.3 of Benaych-Georges+Bordenave+ Knowles looks ideal. Also, good to see Exercise 3.4 in Bollobas' book.